# Ruby: How do you convert a time or date to a friendly url string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For instance, if I have a Time.now, how would I convert that to a friendly url string?

```
Time.now.some_method_here => some_url_friendly_string_here
```

I believe there is a built-in Ruby method to do so, but I can't seem to locate it on Google. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're using Rails (as indicated by your tag), you can use .to_s:

```
Time.now.to_s
```

You can specify a time format to the method, which will format the string differently, such as `Time.now.to_s(:db)`. Please see [this](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb) link for the default date formats. If you don't specify a format, it'll use the same as strftime.

The next part of that page also describes how to add your own time formats, which is very simple:

```
# Initializer
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"

# Any code
Time.now.to_s(:month_and_year) # => September 2010
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything in ruby is open and extensible

```
class Time
  def to_url_string
    self.strftime("%H:%M:%s")
  end
end
```

Comment: Appreciate it Jarrett. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the strftime method.  It's a bit cryptic, but if you look at the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html), you can pick out the year, month, day, etc.

For example, `Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%s")` will give the time in hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the `xmlschema` method which will return a date/time in the format:

```
CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD
```

or

```
CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssTZD
```

depending on the value of the `fraction_digits` argument.

This would give you a time like:

```
2010-09-15T20:31:15+05:00
```

for example.

See the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html) for more info and a link to the code.